# Create sketchfab annotations with API

Tags: 3d, annotations, 3d-modelling

Our company would like to use the Sketchfab API to show building constructions to clients. This works perfect, but we would like to use the feature to create annotations on the 3D models within Sketchfab.

I couldn't find anything about creating/editing annotations with the API they provide. This is possible on the site itself.

Does someone know how to create those annotations with Sketchfab from another site (embedded or with API), or knows about a 3D web modelling program/framework which can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible with new annotation functions:

https://sketchfab.com/developers/viewer/functions#api-section-annotations

> Annotations are notes positionned in 3D space. They allow authors to provide information on a specific part of the model and tell a story.

Specifically https://sketchfab.com/developers/viewer/functions#api-createAnnotation

> ```
> createAnnotation( positionStart, positionEnd, eye, target, title, text, callback, [callback] )
> ```
>
> Create the annotation with the given parameters. Callback will be passed `(err,index)`.

And also https://sketchfab.com/developers/viewer/functions#api-updateAnnotation

> ```
> updateAnnotation( index, {title: title, content: content, eye: eye, target: target}, [callback] )
> ```
>
> Updates the annotation information for the given index. Callback will be passed `(err, information)`.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to add some relevant context around the external documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible yet. But the viewer api should be updated 'soon' to support more feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You are right, I contacted Sketchfab and they are indeed working on it. Just have to wait a little longer...

Comment: https://sketchfab.com/developers/viewer/functions#api-section-annotations